# NSDictionary vs Dictionary type inference in Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2

Xcode 7.1

I am creating a simple layout constraint in Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let search: UISearchBar = UISearchBar.init()

    let viewDict: = ["search" : search, "top" : topLayoutGuide]

    let con1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[search]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict)
    let con2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[top][search]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDict)
    view.addConstraints(con1)
    view.addConstraints(con2)
}
```

This code will not compile and you get:

> "NSDictionary is not convertible to [String: AnyObject]"

It appears that the `viewDict` is type inferred as an `NSDictionary`.
However, the following is inferred as a `Dictionary`:

```
let viewDict = ["search" : search]
```

and the code compiles.

I can fix with explicit typing like so:

```
let viewDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["search" : search, "top" : topLayoutGuide]
```

Question is: Why does adding topLayoutGuide break the type inference?
I would have thought the Swift syntax [:] would always produce a `Dictionary` and that I'd have to use

```
let test: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
test.setValue("hello", forKey: "key1")
```

if I wanted an `NSDictionary`